# issue with self defined structure/ textboxes

Tags: vb.net, structure

here is the situation: 
I have defined a structure called "cell"
in this structure I have included textbox called "display"
my code is this:

```
  Dim new_cell As New cell
  new_cell.display.Multiline = True
```

there are no syntax or run-time "errors" but having put a breakpoint on the second line, when the program gets to it it stops running the sub and carries on as normal, can anybody explain what is the problem?

EDIT
cell definition:

```
   Structure cell

    Dim candidates As List(Of Integer)

    Dim constraints As List(Of Integer)

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer

    Dim display As TextBox
End Structure
```

Comment: Can you post your cell definition?

Comment: If you don't initialise the textbox, you would get a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, the second line of your first code snippet will throw a NullReferenceException.  If that code is in the Load event handler of a form then, on 64-bit systems, the exception will just be swallowed and the only notification will be in the Output window.

If you want a TextBox then you have to create a TextBox.  Where that TextBox gets created depends on what you're trying to achieve.  Regardless, that type should be a class rather than a structure.  You should also think about using properties rather than public fields and you also ought to think about starting appropriate names with an upper-case letter.